# C# How to check textbox

Tags: c#

I'm new in c#, I want to make a small translator with some words.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string i;
    i = textBox1.Text;
    if (textBox1.Text == bonjour) ;
    {
         label1.Text = "Hello";
    }

    if (textBox1.Text == Hello) ;
    {
        label1.Text = "bonjour";
    }
}
```

But label always "bonjour". Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where are you declaring `bonjour` and `Hello`? This code should not compile.

Comment: logically this should work just fine, maybe you have another label in your interface that you are visually validating but you are changing a different one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with some changes.

```
     string i;
        i = textBox1.Text;
        if (textBox1.Text == "bonjour") //Remove the ";" and put quotes around string
        {
            label1.Text = "Hello";
        }

        if (textBox1.Text == "Hello") 
        {
            label1.Text = "bonjour";
        }
```

I would also suggest, if case does not matter, the following:

```
        string i;
        i = textBox1.Text;
        if (textBox1.Text.ToLower() == "bonjour") 
        {
            label1.Text = "Hello";
        }

        if (textBox1.Text.ToLower() == "hello") 
        {
            label1.Text = "bonjour";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string i;
    i = textBox1.Text;
    if (textBox1.Text == "bonjour")
    {
         label1.Text = "Hello";
    }

    if (textBox1.Text == "Hello")
    {
        label1.Text = "bonjour";
    }
}
```

You don't want semicolons at the end of tests.
Also, you need double quotes "" around the strings you're testing for.

With the way you've set this up, you could also do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string i;
    i = textBox1.Text;
    if (i == "bonjour")
    {
         label1.Text = "Hello";
    }

    if (i == "Hello")
    {
        label1.Text = "bonjour";
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you have no way of testing case, so use .ToLower(), as suggested by Matt Cullinan.

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string i;
    i = textBox1.Text;
    if(textBox1.Text == "bonjour");
    {
        label1.Text = "Hello";
    }

    else if(textBox1.Text == "Hello");
    {
        label1.Text = "bonjour";
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if both are being evaluated, both are not gonna be equal since he sets the `Label`s text instead of the `TextBox`s text.

Comment: I can't execute it .